# Knockout.js events not altering UI at pageinit or pageready time, but DO alter UI at click time

Tags: jquery, mobile, knockout.js, observable

JqueryM + knockout.js noob, so please forgive me if this is a dumb question.

I've got a simple page flow operational such that a user can successfully authenticate with the server end.  Great.  Now, what I'd like to do is display a list of values based on their user id.  Console.logging tells me that my server calls are working.

BUT.  My ko.observableArray doens't render the data that I'm putting into it on a call that I know is executing at pageinit time.  If I clone my code into a function that can be called at button click time, things render the way I'd like, but I don't want the user to have to click.  I think that this is probably a timing / cycle thing that I'm not getting.  Here is my code.

.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>



<title>REACH Energy Audit Field Client</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="rte/cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="rte/rte.js"></script>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.0.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ePlusTheme.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/app.css"/>
    <title>e+ Mobile</title>

</head>
<body>


<div id="LoginPage" data-title="LoginPage" data-role="page" data-theme="a">
    <div data-role="content" class="minimalPaddingContent">
        <div class="divDivider"></div>
        <h3>REACH Energy Audit Login</h3>

        <input type="text" placeholder="User Name" id="userName" data-bind="value: userName"/>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password"  id="password" data-bind="value: password"/>

        <a href="#" data-role="button" id="LoginSubmit" style="width:150px;" class="centeredButton" data-bind="click: loginFunction">Sign In, dummy</a>         

        <h3 data-bind="visible: messageLength() > 0">
            <span data-bind="text: responseMessage"></span>
        </h3>

    </div>  
</div>


<div id="auditStubList" data-title="Audit Listing Page" data-role="page" data-theme="a">

    <div data-role="content" class="minimalPaddingContent">
        <div class="divDivider"></div>
        <h3>Audit Listing</h3>


        <Table>
            <tr>
                <td>This is a test row</td>
            </tr>
            <tbody data-bind="foreach: auditStubArray">
                <tr>
                    <td><span data-bind="text: address"></span></td>
                </tr>

            </tbody>
        </Table>
            <a href="#" data-role="button" id="LoginSubmit" style="width:150px;" class="centeredButton" data-bind="click: reportBindings">report bindings</a>           

    </div>  
</div>

<footer>

</footer>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/knockout.2.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/knockout.mapping-latest.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="rte/cordova.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/constants.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/model/loginModel.js"></script>   
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/model/auditStubModel.js"></script>   

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controller/auditStubController.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controller/controllers.js"></script>



    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        app.initialize();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function () {

     this.setupAuditStubListPage(); 

    },

    setupAuditStubListPage: function () {

        $('#auditStubList').on('pagebeforeshow',function(event){

            var auditStubController = new AuditStubController();
            auditStubController.getAuditStubs();

        });

    }

};
```

Here is my controller:

```
var AuditStubController =  function () {
    var self = this;

    self.auditStubArray = ko.observableArray([new auditStub("","","","","","")]);

    self.getAuditStubs = function(){
        // LETS GO AHEAD AND TRY TO GET SOME GODDAMNED AUDIT STUBS!

        var userToken = localStorage.getItem("userToken");
        var theUrl = baseUrl()+"/EnergyAuditing/ws/retrieveAuditStubs.jsonp?callback=auditStubCallback&tokenIn="+userToken;

        console.log("submitting to url: "+ theUrl);

        $.ajax({
            url: theUrl, 
            dataType: "jsonp", 
            jsonp: "callback", 
            jsonpCallback: "auditStubCallback"  , 
            success: function(theData){
                console.log("success!!!");
                    console.log(theData);
                    console.log("the data length is: "+ theData.theAuditStubs.length);

                    for (var z=0;z<theData.theAuditStubs.length;z++){
                        var currentStub = new auditStub(theData.theAuditStubs[z].energyAuditId, 
                                                        theData.theAuditStubs[z].address, 
                                                        theData.theAuditStubs[z].startDateTimeIn, 
                                                        theData.theAuditStubs[z].reachAuditSwIn, 
                                                        theData.theAuditStubs[z].cisCustomerName);

                        self.auditStubArray.push(currentStub);                      
                        console.log(currentStub);

                    }                   
            }
        });
    }

    self.auditStubCallback = function(theData){
        console.log("got to the function!");
    }

    self.reportBindings = function(){
        console.log("got to report bindings");      
        self.auditStubArray.push(new auditStub(1, "942 evergreen terrace", "5/1/2013 8:00 am", "true", "brian" )); 
        // NOTE: ABOVE CALL WORKS; I.E., NEW ADDRESS RENDERS IN UI! 
        // SIMILARLY, IF I MAKE MY AJAX CALL / LOOP / PUSH CALLS HERE, IT WORKS. 
        console.log(self.auditStubArray());
    }


}


ko.applyBindings(new AuditStubController(), document.getElementById("auditStubList"));
```

I know that my code at app.js fires because I can see the console log light up.  I know that the knockout mappings are correct, because if I clone my ajax call and push code to the bogus 'reportBindings' function, everything comes out AOK.

What am I missing, gurus?

Thanks.
brian

Answer (score 0):

I think the setupAuditStubListPage function is called too early.

Try to raplace your app.js code by that :

```
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function () {
    },

    setupAuditStubListPage: function () {
        var auditStubController = new AuditStubController();
        auditStubController.getAuditStubs();
    }
};


$(function () {
    app.setupAuditStubListPage();
})
```

Comment: Hi Damien - Thanks for the quick response.  Unfortunately, that winds up submitting the function before I get a chance to login (i.e., as soon as index.html loads, but I'm displaying the id="loginPage" div).  Without a validated user id, I can't get anything back from the server; when I was waiting for a $("auditStubList").on("pageinit") it was waiting until I called changePage("auditStubList") to fire.